# Fast communication between two Java processes

Tags: java, jvm, protocol-buffers, rmi

I have two small Java applications I want to communicate. There should be a plain request Message and a response in JSON.

*I found two solutions:*

**RMI and Protocol Buffers.**

What would be the fastest way and what the easiest to implement?

Comment: It depends. There is tradeof between logical complicty (i.e. authomatic understanding messages) and low dependency on other libraries. Most basic is socket connection.

Comment: For that specific requirement I (plain text in, JSON out) my first thought would be local (TCP) socket with custom protocol.

Comment: Are you open for suggestions outside the two you found (RMI, ProtoBuf)?

Comment: Sure! I only found these yet

Comment: If you want to use JSON, I suggest using a library like Jackson and Websockets or REST.  These are likely to be more than fast enough. e.g. 20k msgs/sec. If you need more than a million per second, you really need something in binary.

Comment: The thing is that my application I want to communicate with is NOT in a tomcat or any other http machine. So there is no way to let them communicate with REST. I do not really want to pack them into a http server.

Comment: you shouldn't ask for the broadest range possible (between convenience and speed) since the very fastest IPC mechanisms are also quite inconvenient to use and have some restrictions on what you can do with them. it makes your question way too broad.

Answer (score 4):

Neither RMI or ProtocolBuffers meet your requirement.  RMI sends and receives data using Java Object Serialization encodin.  ProtoBuffers also uses its own encoding scheme.  Neither are JSON compatible.

> What would be the fastest way and what the easiest to implement?
>   are suitablestated requirements

Ignoring the above problem ...

- RMI is simpler though that is debatable.  (It depends on how much you know about the two technologies)
- ProtoBuffers will be more efficient.

---

> Saying JSON I mean a String whichs content has the JSON format.

If you are sending and receiving JSON strings and the marshalling / unmarshalling is already taken care of, then the fastest and simplest approach is to use plain `Sockets`.  Neither RMI or ProtoBuffers give you any real value ... in this scenario.

Another alternative is HTTP or HTTPS.  These are more likely to be allowed through firewalls.  HTTPs is also more secure when implemented appropriately.  But that security comes at the cost of performance.

If firewalls are not a concern, then plain socket-level communication is a good option, using either or TCP or UDP depending on the message size, reliability requirements, whether you need one-shot or repeated message exchanges, etcetera.

Comment: Saying JSON I mean a String whichs content has the JSON format. These two options are able to respond string data aren't they?

Comment: Would you recommend a technology outside these two for OP? I am not sure if he really only wants to consider these two.